Gitlab Job services: how to make one service runs after another
I have a test job yml file like this:
test-integration:
  extends:
    - .some_tnner
  image: $SOME_IMAGE
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 'true' 
  services:
    - name: $FIRST_SERVICE
      alias: first-service
    - name: $SECOND_SERVICE
      alias: second-service
  script:
    - 'some_script'

Now I have a issue, The second service is rely on the first one. But now the second service got started in the middle of the first one
How can I let the first service finish first, and then the second one start.
Tried to use

- name: $SECOND_SERVICE
      alias: second-service
      depends_on: first-service

But gitlab thrown error says unknown key: depends_on

I do not see a depends_on in the GitLab-CI syntax, only in docker-compose.
Ideally, try and implement a health check mechanism in the first service's startup script. That way, the script can periodically attempt to connect to the first service or check for a specific file/endpoint indicating the first service's readiness: the second service would only proceed with its main tasks once the health check (from the first service) succeeds.
test-integration:
  extends:
    - .some_tnner
  image: $SOME_IMAGE
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 'true' 
  services:
    - name: $FIRST_SERVICE
      alias: first-service
    - name: $SECOND_SERVICE
      alias: second-service
  script:
    - 'some_script'  # first service
    - './second_service_startup.sh'

second_service_startup.sh
#!/bin/bash

while ! curl -s http://first-service:1234/healthcheck | grep "OK"; do
  echo "Waiting for first-service to be ready..."
  sleep 5
done

echo "first-service is ready! Starting second service tasks..."

# ...

That is a simplified version: you should implement timeouts in your health checks or wait loops to prevent indefinite hangs if the first service fails to start correctly.

Thank you for your advice.
I do have one question: I thought the script will only run after the services and image are up, is that correct?

@PoAhWong Yes, the script section generally runs after the image and services are up. But: services start concurrently, and the script might begin executing before all services are fully ready. That is why I suggested a health check for managing dependencies between services.

I think you want the needs section in the .gitlab-ci.yml file as I show below. You reference the job that must be executed first (i.e. earlier sequence) within your .gitlab-ci.yml file. In the example I have an earlier job called build:image which needs to complete first in order for the job listed below to execute.
jobname:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: registry/myimage:latest
  needs:
    - job: build:image
      artifacts: true   ## optional if the this job should produce artifacts (i.e. reports)

